# Unable to fetch facebook profile picture, to insert in ImageView

Tags: android

I am unable to fetch the facebook profile picture, in order to display it in my fragment. Name, Birthday and link is fetched successfully, however the application stops working when I try to fetch the profile picture. How to get rid of this situation?

```
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback=new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {



    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        AccessToken accessToken=loginResult.getAccessToken();
        Profile profile=Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        //DisplayMessage(profile);

        GraphRequest request=GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                try{

                    tv1=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.name);
                    tv1.setText("Name : " + object.getString("name"));

                    tv2=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.birthday);
                    tv2.setText("BirthDay : " + object.getString("birthday"));

                    tv3=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.id);
                    tv3.setText("link : " + object.getString("link"));

                    String id=object.getString("id");
                    Bitmap mBitmap = getFacebookProfilePicture(id);
                    img.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);

                    /*Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), object.getString("name") + object.getString("birthday") +object.getString("link")
                            , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

                }catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }




            }
        });

        Bundle parameters= new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields","name,birthday,link");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();



    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {

    }
}; 


public Bitmap getFacebookProfilePicture(String userID) {

    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    try {
        URL imageURL = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userID
                + "/picture?type=large");
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageURL.openConnection()
                .getInputStream());

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything you can get.Here is code.

```
 private CallbackManager callbackManager;
 private LoginButton loginButton;
   in OnCreate(){
   loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
   // don't forget to give this.
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile,email,user_birthday"));
      loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        getDetails();
      }
     });
      }
  private void getDetails() {
//for facebook
// FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
 callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
//register callback object for facebook result
  LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                                try {
                                    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                                    if (profile != null) {
                                       String facebook_id = profile.getId();
                                        String f_name = profile.getFirstName();
                                       String l_name = profile.getLastName();
                                        profile_image = profile.getProfilePictureUri(400, 400).toString();
                                    }
                                   String email_id = jsonObject.getString("email"); //email id
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    Logger.logError(e);
                                }
                            }

                        });
```

This surely works.

Check whether you are using this.
com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0

Answer (score 1):

For a quick solution you can get profile picture of user with:

```
String profilePictureUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+userID+"/picture?width=500&height=500";
```

And download with your image loader library to your image view.

Edit:

This is a simple ImageLoading library for Android (old but good)
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Easy to use:
Add it to your project as a gradle dependency.

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.displayImage(profilePictureUrl, yourImageView);
```

Comment: How can I download it with the image loader library to the image view. I am a beginner. Can you please elaborate. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am using like :

```
public void getUserDetailsFromFB(AccessToken accessToken) {

GraphRequest req=GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"graph request completed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try{
            String email =  object.getString("email");
            String birthday = object.getString("birthday");
            String gender = object.getString("gender");
            String name = object.getString("name");
            String id = object.getString("id");
            String photourl =object.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");

        }catch (JSONException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"graph request error : "+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
});
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday,picture.type(large)");
req.setParameters(parameters);
req.executeAsync();
}
```

Then use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)  like : `Picasso.with(context).load(photourl).into(imageView);`

Example `Json` format here :

```
{
  "id": "10204968538960870",
  "name": "Yasin Kaçmaz",
  "email": "yasin_5775@hotmail.com",
  "gender": "male",
  "birthday": "12/06/1994",
  "picture": {
    "data": {
      "is_silhouette": false,
      "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0..."
    }
  }
}
```

You can try `Graph Api` to see example `Json` format in : [Graph Api Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)